# mysql client not found in ubuntu and I can't re-install it!

Tags: 12.04, mysql

(On Ubuntu 12.04) The following terminal output is pretty much self-explanatory:

```
[11:34:28] drossi@d ~/dbdumps$ mysql
The program 'mysql' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install mysql-client-core-5.5
[11:36:12] drossi@d ~/dbdumps$ sudo apt-get install mysql-client-core-5.5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mysql-client-core-5.5 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 20 not upgraded.
[11:36:15] drossi@d ~/dbdumps$ mysql
The program 'mysql' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install mysql-client-core-5.5
```

I tried `apt-get purge`, `apt-get autoclean`... but nothing. The binary is not in usr/bin. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 sudo apt-get install --reinstall mysql-client-core-5.5
```

This will install the package again.